# Inproper connection using RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter

Tags: wireless, networking

Am using Ubuntu 12.10 on a philips MT2400 unit and have a BT Homehub2. Have just brought the TP-Link Wireless N USB adapter (TL-WN823N) to replace a belkin that didn't want to play ball.

It can see the wireless networks nearby fine and is taking an age on boot up to try and connect to the secure network. several attempts fail and I usually have to switch off the wireless using network via system settings and then back on and if I'm lucky that solves the issue and I get a connection established. However this is really sluggish and painfully slow often resulting in web pages failing to load with errors as if there is no connection - There is according to network connection @ 65 Mbps.

Anyone able to help, throw solutions or ideas my way to a: speed up the connection and b: get it to establish on first time at boot?

There is not an issue with the home hub as I can log on via another wireless PC and my phone works fine. And when I connect the Ethernet up it whooshes along fine, so no broadband issue either.

Output from ***sudo lspci -nn***:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 82915G/P/GV/GL/PL/910GL Memory Controller Hub [8086:2580] (rev 0e)
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82915G/P/GV/GL/PL/910GL PCI Express Root Port [8086:2581] (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) High Definition Audio Controller [8086:2668] (rev 04)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #1 [8086:2658] (rev 04)
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #2 [8086:2659] (rev 04)
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #3 [8086:265a] (rev 04)
00:1d.3 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #4 [8086:265b] (rev 04)
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller [8086:265c] (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge [8086:244e] (rev d4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FR (ICH6/ICH6R) LPC Interface Bridge [8086:2640] (rev 04)
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FW (ICH6/ICH6W) SATA Controller [8086:2651] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) SMBus Controller [8086:266a] (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G86 [GeForce 8400 GS] [10de:0422] (rev a1)
02:01.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT2500 Wireless 802.11bg [1814:0201] (rev 01)
02:02.0 Multimedia video controller [0400]: Conexant Systems, Inc. CX23880/1/2/3 PCI Video and Audio Decoder [14f1:8800] (rev 05)
02:02.1 Multimedia controller [0480]: Conexant Systems, Inc. CX23880/1/2/3 PCI Video and Audio Decoder [Audio Port] [14f1:8811] (rev 05)
02:02.2 Multimedia controller [0480]: Conexant Systems, Inc. CX23880/1/2/3 PCI Video and Audio Decoder [MPEG Port] [14f1:8802] (rev 05)
02:03.0 Communication controller [0780]: LSI Corporation V.92 56K WinModem [11c1:048c] (rev 03)
02:04.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6306/7/8 [Fire II(M)] IEEE 1394 OHCI Controller [1106:3044] (rev 80)
02:05.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8169] (rev 10)
```

Output from ***lsusb***:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 192f:0416 Avago Technologies, Pte. 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 058f:9360 Alcor Micro Corp. 8-in-1 Media Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Many thanks in hope and anticipation...

Comment: Could you edit your question, upload the `/var/log/dmesg` log file to some file server, and add the link. Preferably when you are having troubles.

Comment: unfortunatly cant do that...

Comment: Why not? and could you the provide the output of `sudo lsusb -v -s 0bda:8178`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ensure you have the necessary prerequisites:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms git
```

Clone the updated driver with `git`:

```
git clone https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes.git
```

Set it up as a DKMS module:

```
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes
```

Build and install the driver:

```
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.8
```

Refresh the module list:

```
sudo depmod -a
```

Ensure the native (and broken) kernel driver is blacklisted:

```
sudo cp ./rtl8192cu-fixes/blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf /etc/modprobe.d/
```

Let's not take any chances. Instruct Ubuntu to load the new driver when it starts up.

```
echo 8192cu | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Reboot.

### You're done.

<sub>Thanks to [P. Varet](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes) for this awesome fix.</sub>

Comment: I see that you have 7 answers with exactly the same content. How about you do a single question and answer it yourself, then flag all the other 7 questions as duplicated of your self-answered question?

Comment: You post another duplicate answer and I'll suspend you for as long as... just... stop.