# Problem in Ubuntu 12.04 with TL-WN823N

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, realtek

Got a problem with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and TPLink TL-WN823N. Installed the driver from [www.realtek.com.tw](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=277&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true)

Before that I would like to inform that currently there is no internet connection on my Ubuntu 12.04. So I need to download manually the "install file" from my laptop and install it manually.

I already done the following step :

1. First I'm editing the file for blacklist.conf

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
   ```
2. Add lines for :

   ```
   blacklist rtl8192cu 
   blacklist rtl8192c_common 
   blacklist rtlwifi
   ```

   Then save and exit.
3. Install the drivers for realtek 8192CU from `realtek.com.tw`

   Why not using the `rtl8192cu-tjp-dkms_1.6_all.deb` ?

   It works on 13.04 NOT 12.04 as far that I know. it gives me error :

   ```
   Dependency is not satisfiable: dkms (>=1.95)
   ```

   - And do the code below

     ```
     sudo sh install.sh
     ```
   - Got the result like this :

   ```
   ##################################################
   Realtek Wi-Fi driver Auto installation script
   Novembor, 21 2011 v1.1.0

    #################################################
   Decompress the driver source tar ball: rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911.tar.gz
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/runwpa
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_xmit.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ioctl_query.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/efuse/
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_recv.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_br_ext.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_eeprom.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_debug.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_tdls.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_p2p.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ieee80211.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_security.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_cmd.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_mlme.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_mp.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_sreset.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_sta_mgt.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_rf.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_pwrctrl.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_wlan_util.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_mlme_ext.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_io.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ap.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ioctl_rtl.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_mp_ioctl.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ioctl_set.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_iol.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/wlan0dhcp
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/osdep_service.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/pci_ops_linux.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/pci_intf.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/usb_ops_linux.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/hal_com.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/wlan_bssdef.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/cmd_osdep.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_recv.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_mlme_ext.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/wifi.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192c_led.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192d_recv.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/HalPwrSeqCmd.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/Hal8192CPhyReg.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/Hal8192DPhyCfg.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192d_hal.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192c_dm.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192c_rf.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_android.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192c_recv.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/nic_spec.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/usb_osintf.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192d_dm.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_xmit.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192c_event.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_qos.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_pwrctrl.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192c_xmit.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192d_spec.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/osdep_ce_service.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/ieee80211.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/recv_osdep.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/drv_types_linux.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_efuse.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/Hal8192CUHWImg.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/usb_ops.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_ht.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/ioctl_cfg80211.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/ethernet.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/mp_custom_oid.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_ioctl_rtl.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/Hal8192DUHWImg.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192c_spec.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_mlme.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/drv_types.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/Hal8192DEHWImg.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_sreset.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/ieee80211_ext.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/drv_types_ce.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/Hal8192CPhyCfg.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192d_led.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/byteorder/
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/byteorder/swab.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/byteorder/swabb.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/byteorder/big_endian.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/byteorder/little_endian.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/byteorder/generic.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_mp_ioctl.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/usb_ops_linux.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/Hal8192CUHWImg_wowlan.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/Hal8192CEHWImg.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_p2p.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/pci_hal.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/drv_conf.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/usb_vendor_req.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/linux/
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/linux/wireless.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/osdep_service.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/Hal8192DUHWImg_wowlan.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_ioctl_query.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_eeprom.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/drv_types_xp.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_byteorder.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192d_xmit.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_version.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192d_cmd.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_ioctl_set.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/h2clbk.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/pci_osintf.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_cmd.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192d_rf.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/pci_ops.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_tdls.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192c_cmd.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_event.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/mlme_osdep.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_debug.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_ap.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/osdep_intf.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/hal_intf.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/sta_info.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_iol.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_mp_phy_regdef.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_rf.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/usb_hal.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/autoconf.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_security.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_io.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/Hal8192DPhyReg.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_br_ext.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/circ_buf.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/basic_types.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192c_hal.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/ip.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_led.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/if_ether.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/xmit_osdep.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtl8192c_sreset.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_mp.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/rtw_ioctl.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/include/drv_types_sdio.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/ifcfg-wlan0
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/Makefile
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/Kconfig
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/dm.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/hal_intf.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_cmd.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_phycfg.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_xmit.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_dm.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_mp.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rxdesc.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rf6052.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_led.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_halinit.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_recv.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/Hal8192CUHWImg_wowlan.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_ops_ce.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/Hal8192CUHWImg.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_ops_linux.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_xmit.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_ops_xp.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_sreset.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_hal_init.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/hal_com.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/dm.h
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/HalPwrSeqCmd.c
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/clean
   rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911
   Authentication requested [root] for make clean:
   install.sh: 38: [: unexpected operator
   rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod .o ..cmd *.ko *~
   rm .tmp_versions -fr ; rm Module.symvers -fr
   rm -fr Module.markers ; rm -fr modules.order
   cd core/efuse ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod .o ..cmd *.ko
   cd core ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod .o ..cmd *.ko
   cd hal/rtl8192c/usb ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod .o ..cmd *.ko
   cd hal/rtl8192c ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod .o ..cmd *.ko
   cd hal ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod .o ..cmd *.ko
   cd os_dep/linux ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod .o ..cmd *.ko
   cd os_dep ; rm -fr *.mod.c *.mod .o ..cmd *.ko
   Authentication requested [root] for make driver:
   install.sh: 48: [: unexpected operator
   make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-29-generic/build M=/home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911  modules
   make[1]: Entering directory /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic'
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_cmd.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_security.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_debug.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_io.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ioctl_query.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ioctl_set.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ieee80211.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_mlme.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_mlme_ext.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_wlan_util.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_pwrctrl.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_rf.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_recv.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_sta_mgt.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_ap.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_xmit.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_p2p.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_tdls.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_br_ext.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_iol.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/rtw_sreset.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/core/efuse/rtw_efuse.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/hal_intf.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/hal_com.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/dm.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_hal_init.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_phycfg.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rf6052.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_dm.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_rxdesc.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_cmd.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_halinit.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_led.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_xmit.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/rtl8192cu_recv.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/usb_ops_linux.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_sreset.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/rtl8192c_xmit.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/hal/rtl8192c/usb/Hal8192CUHWImg.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/osdep_service.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/usb_intf.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/usb_ops_linux.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/ioctl_linux.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/xmit_linux.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/mlme_linux.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/recv_linux.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.o
     CC [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/rtw_android.o
     LD [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/8192cu.o
     Building modules, stage 2.
     MODPOST 1 modules
     CC      /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/8192cu.mod.o
     LD [M]  /home/all/drivers/8192CU/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/8192cu.ko
   make[1]: Leaving directory/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-29-generic'
   ```

   #

   Compile make driver ok!!

   #

   install.sh: 68: [: unexpected operator
   Authentication requested [root] for remove driver:
   Authentication requested [root] for insert driver:
   Authentication requested [root] for install driver:
   install -p -m 644 8192cu.ko  /lib/modules/3.8.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
   /sbin/depmod -a 3.8.0-29-generic

   #

   The Setup Script is completed !

   ############################################
4. Restart.

   The current condition is that I can connect to my wifi router and can not use firefox to browse anything.

PS :

TL-WN823N is an Realtek 8192CU

My router is Tenda FH303 [www.tp-link.com](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?categoryid=240&model=TL-WN823N). [www.tenda.cn](http://www.tenda.cn/tendacn/product/show.aspx?productid=438)

I use 12.04 in offline PC and no inet connection can be established beside TL-WN823N... That's why really need this one to be connected.

I already read the following links and got stuck.

> http://www.linux-hardware-guide.com/2013-04-21-tp-link-tl-wn823n-mini-wireless-n-usb-300mbps
>   http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=13755671#p13755671
>
> [Inproper connection using RTL8192CU 802.11n WLAN Adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/344364/tp-link-wireless-n-usb-tl-wn823n-connection-issues)
>
> [Compilation error when installing Realtek 8192cu driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/349634/compilation-error-when-installing-realtek-8192cu-driver)
>
> [Cannot install the RTL8188C driver on 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307871/cannot-install-the-rtl8188c-driver-on-13-04?rq=1)
>
> [Cannot install the RTL8188C driver on 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307871/cannot-install-the-rtl8188c-driver-on-13-04?rq=1&newreg=60af2b8ae3144dd68c65240455fd5a43)
>
> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2090580
>
> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2104485
>
> http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2119378

How can I resolve this?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/813461/136964.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo modprobe rtl8192cu
```

Also, you probably have to take your driver off of the blacklist in order for it to work. If you are trying to blacklist the kernel driver but have successfully installed the Realtek version it should not be an issue. I have installed Realtek drivers in the past and the Realtek driver will typically overide or install over the kernel version just as a newer version would during an update. I would try commenting out those three lines you added earlier before doing a reboot to see if that works.
BTW, you need all three of those ones you blacklisted in order for rtl8192cu to work. (rtl8192cu rtlwifi and rtl8192c_common) They all depend on each other and need to be taken off of the blacklist.
After you remove the blacklisted items and reboot.

Now you have to assign the driver to the usb device. So plug the device in.

First, find out the code you need for the following steps. I performed the following for the code '2001 330D'. All you need to do is replace your code for '2001 330D' if your output of lsusb is different.

```
lsusb
```

you should see something like this . . .

```
...
Bus 002 Device 020: ID 2001:330d D-Link Corp.
```

This would indicate your ID is 2001 330D. Again, if your's is different, substitute the correct value in the following commands.

```
sudo modprobe rtl8192cu
echo "2001 330D" | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id
```

To get the driver to load at boot . . .

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

and add the line

```
rtl8192cu
```

Save and exit.

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

and add the following

```
# Declare USB ID to rtl8192cu module
echo "2001 330D" | tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id

exit 0
```

Comment: [http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/277-ubuntu-precise-dwa-131-rev-b1](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/277-ubuntu-precise-dwa-131-rev-b1)

Comment: some how I manage to connect the driver and get linked with the wifi spot. But did not get any data transfer... any idea ??? even ping does not work... And I already replace the TL-WN823N from the store where I bought it.

Comment: ping also give request time out...

Comment: did you try sudo modprobe 8192cu

Comment: I have a Dlink dwa-131 and they have a linux driver from realtek available here, hardware version b [http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-131](http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-131). The end result is sudo modprobe 8192cu instead of rtl8192cu.

Comment: The instructions above use the kernel driver and it is really weak. I downloaded the realtek driver from dlink and the difference is night and day. This is not the same driver from the realtek website as it requires sudo make and sudo make install. However, it is the 8192cu realtek driver for linux.

Comment: the dependencies are `sudo apt-get install gcc build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-`uname -r`

Comment: ah... finally.... after long time to try.... it works :)

Comment: Awesome . . . did you use `sudo modprobe 8192cu`, did you install the driver from dlink, or did you get rtl8192cu working?

Comment: I use the D-Link driver (http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DWA-131.). :)

Comment: Yeah, it works really good. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I've been using and developing on 12.04 lts for three years and never had a problem. I'm ~75 feet away from the access point, through multiple floors and barriers. I have two boxes (D-tops) that are 2 or three feet apart from each other this one has Ubuntu 12.04 lts its upgraded to the 3.8-0-29 image and headers; the other has Bodhi 2.4 (a 12.04 lts based distro with the Enlightenment desktop environment). That change is with in the past two months I swapped to Bodhi on my main box and this box has standard Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, it was the opposite 2 months ago (Main box has better gpu and jacked ddr3 which makes Enlightment look good).

None the less though, I've been using the RTL8192c driver since the 3.2 headers, which was back in late 2011 on 12.04 lts, with an Asus USB-N13 wireless adapter (both boxes have wifi adapters).

This is your POA (plan of action):

In the /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf file you should add the following at the bottom

```
~$ sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

blacklist rtl8192cu
```

In the /etc/modules file you should then add rtl8192c under lp and rtc as shown below:

```
~$ sudo nano /etc/modules

lp
rtc
rtl8192c
```

You do not want to blacklist rtl8192c, rtl8192c_common, rtl8192se, or rtl8192de. The interference is coming from 8192cu. The se and de basically work on both sides of the signal to direct it (laymans terms).

Whats happening is the operating system is 'confused' about which driver and its creating a 'destructive interference' of sorts on the systems calls (or damons). So by blacklisting rtl8192cu and upstarting rtl8192c you are specifically and explicitly instructing the system.

You might want to open up your shells limits as well. I have replied to multiple posts on various websites on how to do so. On the web-page connected to the link below is an example:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/137120/fluctuating-wifi-signal-and-random-disconnects-rtl8192ce/150290#150290

NOTE: If you are using that driver on Bodhi 2.4 which uses a kernel built from split headers 3.8.0-12 and 3.8.0-19 you will not be able to get the install.sh to build the driver and you will get errors. The way around this is to upgrade the headers and kernel image to 3.8.0-44. Then you can build the driver.

You can use the synaptic-package manager's wget script generator to generate the wget script and run the wget script from command line to download the .deb packages.

From there either transfer via thumbdrive or if you carried your box to an ethernet cable hardline then you can install similar to the following example:

```
~$ sudo dpkg -i linux-headers.deb
~$ sudo dpkg -i linux-image.deb
~$ sudo updatedb
~$ sudo reboot
```

Note: I am using pseudo code on those .deb package names.
Upon rebooting delete the extracted rtl folder within the driver folder (assuming you already attempted to install the driver) of the:

```
RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911 > driver > rtl8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911
```

directory. Essentially the folder you extracted from the:

```
RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911.tar.gz
```

Then run execute the install.sh from command line again.

```
~$ sudo bash
:~# chmod +x install.sh
:~# ./install.sh
```

The module will then build and the /sbin/depmod will then be symbolically linked.

Then perform the blacklisting that was stated previously.

TROUBLE SHOOTING: Check the status of both networkmanager and networking which are /etc/init.d/.. files that are to run as upstart jobs in by 'rc.local' (most of the linux system file layouts have came from slack or redhat so forgive me if 'rc.local' is not the Ubuntu specific nomenclature). The development team at Ubuntu has created the upstart services protocol which allows you to check on any upstart job (a process that begins upon system launch/initiation) using the sudo status jobName command. Examples are shown below:

```
~$ sudo status networking
~$ sudo status modemmanager
~$ sudo status network-manager
~$ sudo status cups
```

On the box I am currently writing this post, its a D-top, that uses a built in wifi card that utilizes the b43cutter module. None the less I have had to kill the upstart of modemmanager and networking this is a direct copy and paste from this-boxes terminal output as I type the post, which obviously I am connected to the internet!:

```
mockingbird@mockingbird-OptiPlex-960:~$ status networking
networking stop/waiting
mockingbird@mockingbird-OptiPlex-960:~$ status modemmanager
modemmanager stop/waiting
mockingbird@mockingbird-OptiPlex-960:~$ status network-manager
network-manager start/running, process 924
```

That output basically states that networking is not working (I commented out the start point and esac command with in the file), modemmanager is not running (i did the exact same thing), but network-manager is running (which has over ride authority on networking anyways), and the b43 module was added as shown to the modules file as a start up job:

```
~$ sudo nano /etc/modules

# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

lp
rtc
b43
```

I have stated this to give you some ideas for trouble shooting strategies, open your mind up so to speak.

NOTE: If you are still having problems with 'signal fadage', try setting the essid and rate, check first to see what the name of your wifi interface is (should be wlan0), it might be wlan1, or poop1 for all i know, you can check by running the following command and verifying the output:

```
~$ sudo ifconfig -a
```

NOTE: IF YOU ARE A UNIX/BSD/SOLARIS HEAD, WHO FOUND THIS POST FROM YOU BROWSERS SEARCH HIT ON THE RTL8192 DRIVER, YOU SHOULD KNOW THAT LINUX USERS AND THE COMMANDS USUALLY REFER TO THE INTERFACE AS WHAT YOU WOULD CALL A MEDIA TYPE, SO THE DATALINK=THE INTERFACE ON LINUX.. ALSO YOU DO NOT NOT HAVE THE FOLLOWING COMMAND iwconfig WHICH IS ONE OF THE MOST USEFUL COMMNANDS IN TERMS OF COMMAND LINE NETWORK CONTROL.

You should probably stop and then restart network services before and after running the following iwconfig commands, this will allow the changes to become current with out re-booting the system more than likely (unless the system is explicitly told so), the system would not hold the changes through a re-boot.

First click on the top panel on your wifi indicator, de-select 'Enable Networking', then run the following commands

```
~$ sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager stop
~$ sudo /etc/init.d/modemmanager stop
~$ sudo /etc/init.d/networking stop

~$ sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid "Your Networks name"
~$ sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate 30M
```

Then restart the original upstart jobs by adding start at the end of the command instead of stop.

NOTE: YOU SHOULD ALSO DOCUMENT AND BE-AWARE OF THE EFFECTS THIS CAUSES THE S35NETWORKING JOB PROCESS!!!!

Some of those adapters have incredible specs, like Gb/s type signal strength/output but yet your internet subscription, your router, and your box; aren't capable of that type induction/resonance (data transfer).

That type of strength has many demands on the system besides just radio frequency. Those antenna's/adpaters/recievers/transmitters require incredible I/O and voltage demands from the system and the kernel, to perform that kind of frequency scaling. Now if you are only pay for an IT subscription of 50 Mb/s on the down and 20 on the up, but yet when you right click on your wifi indicator and scroll down and select connection information and you see some UBERED 300Mb/s, that reading is wacked out. Its not coming from kernel's utility measure, its coming from the kernels hardware probe, (You want further explanation either pay me, or pay the student loans it takes to study multivariable calculus a couple of computer engineering courses, which you cant even touch till you've had multiple programming classes and 3 or 4 electrical engineering courses at a math level of differential equations studying topics of Laplace transforms, signals and system controls, which is well a year or more above Calculus 2 w/ analytical geometry).

By setting your specs to a regulated rate you give yourself (your connection) a test limit.

If you notice that the connection is no longer breaking like it was, the wifi indicator on the unity-panel is not blinking and waving as if its searching for the connection,

Then create a script similiar to the following and add it to the /etc/init.d directory, entitle the script iwanconfig_options:

```
~$ sudo nano /etc/init.d/iwanconfig_options

#! /bin/sh
IWCONFIG="/usr/sbin/iwconfig_opts"
IWCONFIG_OPTS="rate 30M"
DEV="wlan0"
case "$1" in
start)
     echo -n "Setting the $DEV options to $IWCONFIG_OPTS...";
     $IWCONFIG -s $DEV $IWCONFIG_OPTS;
     echo " done.";;
stop)
    ;;
esac
exit 0
```

Change the mode of access of the script to exectuable

```
~$ sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/iwanconfig_options
```

Now Create a file in the /usr/sbin/ direcrtory called iwconfig_opts, symbolically link 
it to the /sbin/iwoconfig binary.

Effectively you are creating an update alternatives type situation, just to open your minds up alittle bit, or the the bash to dash interaction could also be used as an analogy in terms of what you are trying to achieve in terms of communication/execution. You want it to be fast though, because it is at start up!

Then update the upstart services symbolic links to your newly made script

```
~$ sudo update-rd.d iwanconfig_options defaults
```

Reboot the system and the configuration object will be persistent.

Good luck.

I tell you what, you'll are lucky, I had to read the documentation and the README text to figure that stuff out! Total it was only 10 thousand pages (8.5 x 11).